# How to simulate arrivals of clients according to the schedule

Tags: python, simpy

I want to simulate customers arrivals at specific time periods (not generated according to statistical distribution). The arrival times are defined in the csv file that I loaded into pandas dataframe `df`:

```
df.head()

arrival_time  start_service  end_service  waiting_time  service_duration
09:00:20      09:01:00       09:06:00     0.40      5.00
09:01:00      09:02:20       09:04:00     1.20      1.40
```

This is my current code, but I don't know how to force the entities (clients) to arrive according to the schedule defined in `df`, e.g. at `09:00:20`, then at `09:01:00`, etc. I assume that I should also set the starting simulation time in the `Environment`, but how can I do it? (I don't need the real-time simulation):

```
import random
import simpy
import pandas as pd

def source(env, df, counter):
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        c = client(env, 'Client%02d' % i, counter, row, time_in_bank=row["service_duration"])
        env.process(c)   

def client(env, name, counter, row, time_in_bank):
    arrive = env.now # probably some changes to be done here
    print('%s arrived at %7.4f' % (name,arrive))

    with counter.request() as req:
        results = yield req

        wait = env.now - row["waiting_time"]

        print('%s waited %6.3f' % (name, wait))

        yield env.timeout(time_in_bank)
        print('%s exited the office at %7.4f' % (name, env.now))


df = pd.read_csv("arrivals.csv",sep=",",header=0)

env = simpy.Environment()

counter = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(source(env, df.head(), counter))
env.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- convert datetime objects to timestamps and work with these
- Define an *initial_time* that you pass to `Environment()`
- Define how long one SimPy step is, e.g. `1 step == 1 sec`

Example (featuring [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)):

```
import arrow
import simpy

start = arrow.get('2016-11-05T00:00:00')
env = simpy.Environment(initial_time=start.timestamp)

def proc(env):
    print('Proc start at', env.now, arrow.get(env.now))
    yield env.timeout(10)  # 10 seconds
    print('Proc stop at ', env.now, arrow.get(env.now))

p = env.process(proc(env))
env.run(p)
```

Output:

```
Proc start at 1478304000 2016-11-05T00:00:00+00:00
Proc stop at  1478304010 2016-11-05T00:00:10+00:00
```

Comment: Do you have some small example?

Comment: Added an example to my answer